# Why Log4J2 root logger consumes all log levels from the child loggers?

Tags: java, log4j2

Project at job (written in Java) uses:

1. spring-context 5.0.6
2. spring-test 5.0.6
3. log4j-api 2.11
4. log4j-core 2.11
5. log4j-jcl (as a bridge to get log events from Spring's bowels and to utilize logger in test classes, obtained from extending *AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests*)
6. ... and some other dependencies like Selenium, MyBatis, TestNG to write autotests ...

   So, I wrote YAML configuration file and everything works as I want (loggers bind to appenders, appenders write log data to files), but root logger consumes all log events from child loggers even if its own log level is WARN and child's one is DEBUG or TRACE. Of course, I can use workaround - simply set *additivity* to *false*, but I don't like to turn off log event propagation - it is quite useful and that's why I want root logger to behave as expected by default - to pass **more** specific log levels and ignore **less** specific log events from the child loggers.
   Clarify this, please.
   Thanks in advance.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>samsonpost</groupId>
    <artifactId>samsonpost-htmlelements</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.5</aspectj.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.springframework.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlelements-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                        <version>2.21.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Log4J2 YAML Configuration

```
Configuration:
  name: samsonpost-logging-configuration

  Properties:
    Property:
      name: log-path
      value: "logs"

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: stdout
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n"

    File:
      - name: sp_sql
        filename: ${log-path}/sp_sql.log
        append: false
        immediateFlush: true
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n"

      - name: php_execute_script
        filename: ${log-path}/php_execute_script.log
        append: false
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n"

      - name: js_execute_script
        filename: ${log-path}/js_execute_script.log
        append: false
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n"

      - name: test
        filename: ${log-path}/test.log
        append: false
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n"

      - name: log_files_operation
        filename: ${log-path}/log_files_operation.log
        append: false
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n"

      - name: webdriver
        filename: ${log-path}/webdriver.log
        append: false
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n"
  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: WARN
      AppenderRef:
        ref: stdout

    Logger:
      - name: ExecutePHPScript
        level: DEBUG
        AppenderRef:
          ref: php_execute_script

      - name: ExecuteJSScript
        level: DEBUG
        AppenderRef:
          ref: js_execute_script

      - name: services
        level: INFO
        AppenderRef:
          ref: test

      - name: db.entity.sp.core
        level: DEBUG
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          ref: sp_sql

      - name: wd
        level: DEBUG
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          ref: webdriver
```

Example of a test class:

```
package services.requestInt;

import common.UserID;
import constants.UrlsConst;
import db.entity.sp.services.requestInt.RequestIntService;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import po.sp.blocks.popUpWindow.SelectionPopUp;
import po.sp.blocks.popUpWindow.elements.SelectUserPopUpElements;
import po.sp.pages.authorization.AuthorizePage;
import po.sp.pages.services.documents.softdev.IntCreateNewOrderPage;
import po.sp.pages.services.documents.softdev.IntDetailOrderPage;
import po.sp.pages.services.documents.softdev.IntListOrderPage;
import project.init.SpringConfiguration;
import wd.wait.DriverWaitElement;

import static constants.UrlsConst.LIST_REQUEST_INT_PORTAL;
import static services.requestInt.cfg.RequestIntMissionProperty.*;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfiguration.class)
public class RejectOrderByManagerOrApprover extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired private IntListOrderPage intListOrderPage;
    @Autowired private IntCreateNewOrderPage intCreateNewOrderPage;
    @Autowired private IntDetailOrderPage intDetailOrderPage;
    @Autowired private SelectionPopUp<SelectUserPopUpElements> popUpSelectUser;
    @Autowired private AuthorizePage authorizePage;
    @Autowired private WebDriver driver;
    @Autowired private RequestIntService requestIntService;

    private Integer orderOrdinalNumber;

    @Test
    public void createOrder() {
        logger.info("Создаём заказ под Грибановым и отправляем менеджеру на согласование");
        authorizePage.authById(UserID.GRIBANOV.getUserId());
        driver.get(LIST_REQUEST_INT_PORTAL);
        DriverWaitElement.waitElementToBeClickable(driver, By.xpath(".//a[@for-tests='link-create']"), 15);
        intListOrderPage.createNewOrder();
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".side-panel-iframe")));
        intCreateNewOrderPage.selectProject(PROJECT_NAME);
        intCreateNewOrderPage.setProblem(SITE_PROBLEM);
        intCreateNewOrderPage.setSolution(SITE_SOLUTION);
        intCreateNewOrderPage.addApprover();
        popUpSelectUser.setUser("Верещагин");
        popUpSelectUser.clickUserById(UserID.VERETSHAGIN);
        intCreateNewOrderPage.saveOrder();
        intDetailOrderPage.sendToManagerForApproval();
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "createOrder")
    public void rejectByManager() {
        logger.info("Авторизуемся под менеджером (Новосельцев) и отклоняем заказ");
        authorizePage.authById(UserID.NOVOSELTSEV.getUserId());
        orderOrdinalNumber = Integer.valueOf(requestIntService.findLastRequest().getCode());
        driver.get(UrlsConst.DETAIL_REQUEST_INT_PORTAL + orderOrdinalNumber.toString() + "&IFRAME=Y&IFRAME_TYPE=SIDE_SLIDER");
        intDetailOrderPage.clickButtonRejectByManager();
        // Авторизуемся под Грибановым, вводим описание проблемы
        logger.info("Авторизуемся под Грибановым, вводим описание проблемы, отправляем менеджеру на согласование");
        authorizePage.authById(UserID.GRIBANOV.getUserId());
        driver.get(UrlsConst.DETAIL_REQUEST_INT_PORTAL + orderOrdinalNumber.toString() + "&IFRAME=Y&IFRAME_TYPE=SIDE_SLIDER");
        intDetailOrderPage.clickButtonEdit();
        intCreateNewOrderPage.setProblem(SITE_REJECT_PROBLEM);
        intCreateNewOrderPage.attachFile(FILE_UPLOAD);
        intCreateNewOrderPage.saveOrder();
        intDetailOrderPage.sendToManagerForApproval();
        // Авторизуемся под Новосельцевым и согласовываем
        logger.info("Авторизуемся под мендежером (Новосельцев) и согласовываем");
        authorizePage.authById(UserID.NOVOSELTSEV.getUserId());
        driver.get(UrlsConst.DETAIL_REQUEST_INT_PORTAL + orderOrdinalNumber.toString() + "&IFRAME=Y&IFRAME_TYPE=SIDE_SLIDER");
        intDetailOrderPage.clickButtonApprove();
        // Авторизуемся под Верещагиным и отклоняем
        logger.info("Авторизуемся под Верещагиным и отклоняем");
        authorizePage.authById(UserID.VERETSHAGIN.getUserId());
        driver.get(UrlsConst.DETAIL_REQUEST_INT_PORTAL + orderOrdinalNumber.toString() + "&IFRAME=Y&IFRAME_TYPE=SIDE_SLIDER");
        intDetailOrderPage.setCommentToTask("Захотел и отменил!");
        intDetailOrderPage.clickButtonRejectByApprover();
        // Авторизуемся под Грибановым
        logger.info("Авторизуемся под Грибановым");
        authorizePage.authById(UserID.GRIBANOV.getUserId());
        driver.get(UrlsConst.DETAIL_REQUEST_INT_PORTAL + orderOrdinalNumber.toString() + "&IFRAME=Y&IFRAME_TYPE=SIDE_SLIDER");
        intDetailOrderPage.clickButtonEdit();
        intCreateNewOrderPage.setProblem("Ну такое себе");
        intCreateNewOrderPage.saveOrder();
    }
}
```

*stdout* output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java" -ea -Dspring.profiles.active=chrome -Dlog4j2.disableJmx=true -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53036:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\plugins\testng\lib\testng-plugin.jar;D:\samsonpost\target\test-classes;D:\samsonpost\target\classes;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\ru\yandex\qatools\htmlelements\htmlelements-java\1.19\htmlelements-java-1.19.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.12.0\selenium-java-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.12.0\selenium-api-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.12.0\selenium-chrome-driver-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.12.0\selenium-edge-driver-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.12.0\selenium-firefox-driver-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.12.0\selenium-ie-driver-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.12.0\selenium-opera-driver-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.12.0\selenium-remote-driver-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.12.0\selenium-safari-driver-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.12.0\selenium-support-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.3\byte-buddy-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.14.3\testng-6.14.3.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.6.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.5\jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.5\jackson-core-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-yaml\2.9.5\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.18\snakeyaml-1.18.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-jcl\2.11.0\log4j-jcl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.0\log4j-api-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.11.0\log4j-core-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.4\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.2\gson-2.8.2.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\23.6-jre\guava-23.6-jre.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.3\httpclient-4.5.3.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.6\httpcore-4.4.6.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.9.1\okhttp-3.9.1.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.13.0\okio-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.46\mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.72\jcommander-1.72.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\apache-extras\beanshell\bsh\2.0b6\bsh-2.0b6.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\com\alibaba\fastjson\1.2.33\fastjson-1.2.33.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\mybatis\mybatis-spring\1.3.2\mybatis-spring-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\mybatis\mybatis\3.4.6\mybatis-3.4.6.jar;C:\Users\glukhov\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\plugins\testng\lib\jcommander.jar" org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket53035 @w@C:\Users\glukhov\AppData\Local\Temp2\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp C:\Users\glukhov\AppData\Local\Temp2\idea_testng.tmp
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/glukhov/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 3968
Only local connections are allowed.
июн. 07, 2018 5:15:40 ПП org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
2018-06-07 17:15:41,448 INFO  - Создаём заказ под Грибановым и отправляем менеджеру на согласование
2018-06-07 17:16:28,646 INFO  - Авторизуемся под менеджером (Новосельцев) и отклоняем заказ
2018-06-07 17:16:40,269 INFO  - Авторизуемся под Грибановым, вводим описание проблемы, отправляем менеджеру на согласование
2018-06-07 17:17:18,522 INFO  - Авторизуемся под мендежером (Новосельцев) и согласовываем
2018-06-07 17:17:28,654 INFO  - Авторизуемся под Верещагиным и отклоняем
2018-06-07 17:17:40,732 INFO  - Авторизуемся под Грибановым

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html

Comment: I have already read it before posting the question. Thanks anyway.